# Is there any method to find the ip address of nearest access point in my wifi network?

Tags: java, python, objective-c, network-programming, network-protocols

I use inssider and kismac for checking the wifi indoor and outdoor accesspoints in my network. But both these tools doesn't provide any info on the ip of the access point currently connected. Its seen that netstumbler in windows had an option to display ip address and subnet but, though they have the fields, it doesn't display anything. I don't find any app that fulfills this requirement.

Is there any method to find the ip address of the nearest accesspoint in my wifi network? programmatically or is there any app?

is there any method in python , objective c , java where a request for ip-address of an ap returns it.

I use osx 10.9

Comment: Dont know about osx but for java u can see this example http://www.androidsnippets.com/scan-for-wireless-networks

Comment: i tried the android snippet. It's working but not giving what I wanted. what i wanted is ip address of ap. like I said its giving the mac address, ssid , frequency etc... no ip yet...

Comment: U cant get ip of ap without connecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

use following way to achieve

```
public String getIpAddr() {
       WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
       WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
       int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();

       String ipString = String.format(
       "%d.%d.%d.%d",
       (ip & 0xff),
       (ip >> 8 & 0xff),
       (ip >> 16 & 0xff),
       (ip >> 24 & 0xff));

       return ipString;
    }
```

Please Note: You need to add android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in your AndroidManifest.xml as  to access the code.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

for google play similar type of app look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roamingsoft.manager&hl=en

Comment: Mmmh ... OP is asking for OSX and I will bet `getIPAddress()` is the clients IP not of the AP ...

Comment: It is the IP of nearest access point that have to be discovered not that of client.  Is there any method programmatic ally or other , this can be done in osx

Answer (score 0):

You cant get ip of AP without connecting to it.

You can get ip of connected AP by following

```
DhcpInfo dhcp;
    WifiManager wifii;
        wifii = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        dhcp = wifii.getDhcpInfo();

        s_dns1 = "DNS 1: " + String.valueOf(dhcp.dns1);
        s_dns2 = "DNS 2: " + String.valueOf(dhcp.dns2);
        s_gateway = "Default Gateway: " + String.valueOf(dhcp.gateway);
        s_ipAddress = "IP Address: " + String.valueOf(dhcp.ipAddress);
        s_leaseDuration = "Lease Time: " + String.valueOf(dhcp.leaseDuration);
        s_netmask = "Subnet Mask: " + String.valueOf(dhcp.netmask);
        s_serverAddress = "Server IP: " + String.valueOf(dhcp.serverAddress);
```

Comment: i am inside the network.it works but it doesn't fulfill what i want. this code displays the all details like dns my ip server ip subnet mask . but it doesn't give the details of the outdoor access-point through which i am connected to this router. what i want is the ip of the nearest outdoor access point

Comment: See,an access-point helps to connect wireless devices to a wired network. By outdoor I meant an access-point is outside the building. Indoor access-point meant its inside the building. These access-points are connected to the router through a switch. When using the above code i'm getting the ip and other details of the router like subnet mask. What i am looking for is , when I turn on wifi near an access point and use any of the tool or code ( i'm also the member of the network), i should be getting the ip of the outdoor/indoor access-point THAT I AM CONNECTED TO not the router.

Comment: ip-scanner in osx will list every devices in my network including the access-point. What I am looking for is an app or code which will say the ip address of the access point I AM CURRENTLY CONNECTED TO.   is there any way. https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/ip-scanner/id404167149?mt=12